# JvmName annotation not working for android `ViewModel` with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, overloading

I have a `ViewModel` where I want to have 2 functions with the same signature but different implementation. obviously I got the error "conflicting overloads". I used to be able to solve this with the annotation `@JvmName`, but it is not working for some reason.

here is my code:

```
abstract class LoadingViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _loadingState = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val loadingState = _loadingState.asStateFlow()

    @JvmName("setLoadingStateSuspended")
    suspend fun setLoadingState(isLoading: Boolean) = _loadingState.emit(isLoading)

    fun setLoadingState(isLoading: Boolean) {
        _loadingState.value = isLoading
    }
}
```

did something change? is it still possible to do? if so, how?